# Bootstrap 4.3.1 Modal not wokring

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I am having difficulties getting this part of my html/php page working, everything else works fine except the modal.
I am using Bootstrap 4.3.1 in the template I am using, i have followed a lot of other post's on SOF but none seem to work. The following code is where it gets called from

```php
<a data-toggle="modal" href="vehicles.php#vehicle_delete_<? echo $row->id;?>" class="btn btn-light"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
```

and the modal section;

```php
<?  if ($_SESSION['admin_level']>=3) {  ?>
            <div class="modal fade" id="vehicle_delete_<? echo $row->id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Delete <? echo $row->classname;?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <form method="post" action="vehicles.php#vehicles_delete_<? echo $row->id;?>" role="form"> 
                                    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="delete" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? echo $row->id;?>" />
                                    <p>Do you really want to delete the Vehicle "<? echo $row->classname;?>" from the User <? echo $row->name;?>?</p>                                    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal" type="reset">Cancel</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit">Delete Vehicle</button>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                
<?  } ?>
```

I have the same exact code on an version v3.3.5 of Bootstrap and it works quiet fine, but since upgrading to the version I am currently using in this template, it no longer works.

The following is the footer

```html
 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
 <!-- simplebar js -->
  <script src="assets/plugins/simplebar/js/simplebar.js"></script>
  <!-- sidebar-menu js -->
  <script src="assets/js/sidebar-menu.js"></script>
  <!-- loader scripts -->
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.loading-indicator.js"></script>
  <!-- Custom scripts -->
  <script src="assets/js/app-script.js"></script>
  <!-- Chart js -->
  
  <script src="assets/plugins/Chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
 
  <!-- Index js -->
  <script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
```

The following is the header

```html
<!-- loader-->
  <link href="assets/css/pace.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="assets/js/pace.min.js"></script>
  <!--favicon-->
  <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Vector CSS -->
  <link href="assets/plugins/vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- simplebar CSS-->
  <link href="assets/plugins/simplebar/css/simplebar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- animate CSS-->
  <link href="assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- Icons CSS-->
  <link href="assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <!-- Sidebar CSS-->
  <link href="assets/css/sidebar-menu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Custom Style-->
  <link href="assets/css/app-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Regards.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow!
In order to reproduce your issue, would you please share the client side code, as retrieved by the browser? use the 'view source' option, or simply `ctrl+u`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @noamgaash

https://sqfbin.com/uyarerijohufideluvib

Comment: Why are you using an anchor `href="vehicles.php?"` and a `data-toggle="modal"` on the same go? So the page refreshes once you click it, and the modal doesn't appear? Because the page refreshes, no? Please elaborate on how it is not working or what's happening.

Comment: Hi @TimVermaelen - I honestly couldn't tell you. I was given some backend code, and asked to port it to a new theme. How it is, above is how it is in the backend code, which somehow works quiet fine exactly the way it is. Im confused on it also

Comment: So it seems you're missing some code to stop to default event from the button => `href`, and port the `href` to the form action/hidden input fields. Then the form in the button should work. We could write it a bit better tho.

Comment: @TimVermaelen - Not quiet sure what I could be missing, the new theme port is essentially the exact same as the original, just newer bootstrap and different theme.

Comment: Have you looked for "vehicle_delete" inside JavaScript files or anywhere else?

Comment: Probably one of script file is missing, I tried with CDN it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add data-target on the buttons?

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vehicle_delete_<? echo $row->id;?>" class="btn btn-light"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
```

Could be Bootstrap 3 prevents the default behavior on the href, but Bootstrap 4 doesn't.

Comment: This and the above both worked the same. The modal info now show's up, although the text and everything inside of it is behind the modal, instead of in the modal. Probably something I've done

Comment: Something with the `modal-backdrop` or how do you mean? :)
If you're good on your own that's fine, otherwise let us know ^^
Btw, does this code generates x amount of modals for every record you can delete?

Comment: Sorry, I wish i could word things correctly, apoligies... Picture -> [link](https://gyazo.com/f0638898cc6578db4508c5d097654e6e)

Comment: Or all your text is white. Could try with a bg-dark class on the modal?

Comment: Yes, it generates X amount of models depending which record I have clicked the button for.

The text was white, you were correct. I added red <font> tags around just the text, and it is on the model just white text.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud add data-target instead of href

from this to

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="vehicles.php#vehicle_delete_<? echo $row->id;?>" class="btn btn-light"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
```

This

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="" class="btn btn-light" data-target="#vehicle_delete_<? echo $row->id;?>"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
```

Then after you have to pass the URL to Delete vehicle button

Comment: This and the below both worked the same. The modal info now show's up, although the text and everything inside of it is behind the modal, instead of in the modal. Probably something I've done